# Java - Easy way to read/write/search separated data blocks on file

Tags: java, io

I searched thoroughly on the web about this issue but I didn't find anything. Sorry for my bad english, but it's also kinda difficult to explain.
I would like to know if there is a simple method or, perhaps, a library, which allows to read/write and identify data blocks (for example, strings) on a file without caring of low level details such as "read until you found this delimeter, then return what you've read" or "write everything, then put this delimeter".
In particular, given a text file like this:

```
//Data Block 1

//Some kind of delimiter automatically generated

//Data Block 2

...

//Data Block n
```

The application must **automatically**:

- Write another data block after the last one on the file;
- Iterate on all the data blocks and return each one of them;
- Access a random datablock (i.e I want to read the third data block currently on file).

Maybe I just can use a data structure, put the data in separately, then serialize the object on file, but I wonder if exists a much cheaper way like the one described before.

Thanks in advance and, again, sorry for the possibly confused explanation.

Comment: The simplest API might be to use a persisted Map. E.g. Chronicle Map, or a journal like Chronicle Queue. How particular are you about the file format?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). You might just use a simple local database, like [embedded Apache Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html), rather than trying to create your own blocks and indexes manually in a file.

Comment: Following with the assumption that this is an XY problem, I'll ask: What do you hope to achieve by doing this? Why write and index data blocks in a file? Are you sure this is the way it needs to be done?